# syntax of query sql in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have 2 table in my database:

first :  Structure of table `pointdevente`

```
Colonne Type    Null    Défaut
IdPointDeVente  int(11) Non 
NomPDV  varchar(50) Non 
Lat varchar(10) Non 
Long    varchar(10) Non 
Tel1    varchar(50) Non 
Tel2    varchar(50) Non 
Site    varchar(50) Non 
Email   varchar(50) Non 
MotDePasse  varchar(50) Non 
NomCommercant   varchar(50) Non 
DateIns date    Non 
DateExp date    Non
```

---

Second: Structure of table `produit`

```
Colonne Type    Null    Défaut
IdProduit   int(11) Non 
Libelle varchar(100)    Non 
Designation varchar(300)    Non 
Prix    double  Non 
Stock   int(11) Non 
IdPDV   int(11) Non 
IdCategorie int(11) Non 
Image   varchar(50) Non
```

---

question is how to show the name of `nomPDV` who is in table `pointdevente` in `product.php`
(sorry for my english)

```
<table>
    <?php   
    while ($a=mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
        ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="unit-price"><?=$a['IdProduit'];?></span></td>
                <td>
                    <a class="entry-thumbnail" data-toggle="lightbox"><img src=../images/<?php echo $a['Image']?> width="62px" height="82px"/></a>
                    <a href="../product.php?idproduit=<?=$a[IdProduit];?>" class="entry-url"><p><?=$a['Libelle'];?></p></a>
                    <a class="entry-title" href="product.html"></a>
                </td>
                <td><span class="unit-price"><?=$a['Libelle'];?></span></td>
                <td width="11%"><span class="unit-price"><?=$a['Designation'];?></span></td>
                <td><strong class="text-bold row-total"><span class="unit-price"><?=$a['Prix']." DT";?></span></strong></td>
                <td><span class="unit-price"><?=$a['Stock'];?></span></td>
                <td><span class="unit-price">
                    <?php
                        $nopdv = $a['IdPDV'];
                        $query = mysql_query("SELECT NomPDV from pointdevente WHERE IdPointDeVente=".$nopdv);
                        echo $query;
                    ?>
                </span></td>
                <td><span class="unit-price"><?=$a['IdCategorie'];?></span></td>
                <td class="hidden-xs"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="window.open('supprimer_produit.php?id_produit=<?=$a['IdProduit'];?>')">Supprimer</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you mean in the place where you wrote:

```
echo $query
```

You want it to output the value extracted from the database? Replace that line with:

```
echo mysql_result($query, 0);
```